# PTX - where are .reg registers located?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, ptx

When I use `.reg` to declare registers.. where are they?

I mean: if I use `.reg` inside a device function registers are stored on the register file that each thread has... but what if I declare a `.reg` variable in the module in the global scope (not `.global`, simply global scope)?

Comment: What do you mean by "where" and "located" in the context of a state space in a virtual machine?

Comment: I mean where is it allocated: register file on a thread? Even if I declare a .reg name on a global scope and NOT inside a kernel?

Comment: It is "allocated" in the register state space of the virtual machine (and this is only allowed in non CUDA ABI PTX code).

Comment: Got it. I intend to conform to ABI-abiding PTX. Thanks, make it an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `.reg` declaration winds up in the PTX register state space. How that maps to hardware features is determined by the assembler, but the usual rules of register or local memory hold true. You should be aware that register state space declarations at module scope are only supported in PTX 1.x and 2.x code and can't be used with the CUDA ABI. The PTX documentation notes:

> Registers differ from the other state spaces in that they are not
>   fully addressable, i.e., it is not possible to refer to the address of
>   a register. When compiling to use the Application Binary Interface
>   (ABI), register variables are restricted to function scope and may not
>   be declared at module scope. When compiling legacy PTX code (ISA
>   versions prior to 3.0) containing module scoped .reg variables, the
>   compiler silently disables use of the ABI.